# Copy contents of subfolder to another folder

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, copy

For example I have a folder structure like below

```
             Parent
|--------|-------|-------|-------|
Fol1   Fol2    Fol3    Fol4    Fol5
|       |       |       |       |
Sub1   Sub2    Sub3    Sub4    Sub5
|       |       |       |       |
File1  File2   File3   File4   File5
```

How can I copy the contents and of the subdirectories of the Parent folder to a New Directory.
I want the structure to be like this:

```
            New Directory
|-------|-------|-------|-------|
Sub1   Sub2    Sub3    Sub4    Sub5
|       |       |       |       |
File1  File2   File3   File4   File5
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Test this:

```
@echo off
cd /d "parent"
for /d %%a in (*) do xcopy "%%a\*.*" "d:\new directory\" /s/h/e/k/f/c
```

Comment: that `xcopy` paramter combo: `/s/h/e/k/f/c` xD

Comment: @Monacraft Search usenet for "she loves kfc" and you'll find the author of that term, and why it's phrased that way. :)  I think you have to be a certain age to 'get it' because Kentucky Fried Chicken changed their name to KFC many years ago now - here at least.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@echo off
set parent=C:\Path\To\Parent\
set target=C:\Path\To\New Directory\

cd "%parent%"
for /d %%a in (*) do (
pushd "%%~a"
for /d %%b in (*) do (
md "%target%\%%~b"
copy "%%~b\*" "%target%\%%~b\"
)
popd
)
```

And that should do what you want it to. Note it hasn't been tested yet.